# Is the regex syntax in .net 3.5 the same as the regex syntax in the latest version of .net framework in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regular-expressions

Is the regex syntax in .net 3.5 the same as the regex syntax in the latest version of .net framework in c#?

Comment: If it's changed, then do you now have three problems?

Comment: @MasonWheeler, I will not have a problem, I just want to learn how to use it.

Comment: That's actually referencing an old joke about how if you try to solve a problem with regular expressions, now you have two problems.

Comment: @MasonWheeler sorry did not now.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from what I understand the .NET regex flavor has not changed since 1.0.